# ¿Cómo puedo limitar el número de caracteres en un entry en Python?

Tags: python, condiciones, sqlite3

El siguiente código esta enlazado a una base de datos, pero necesito que solo me acepte 9 dígitos, ya probe con un while if, pero el While me dice que el StringVar() no tiene parámetros len asignados, trato de asignarlos pero me sigue dando error.
La base de datos con la que estoy trabajando es sqlite3 y ya defini el la entrada de datos como 9

```
class Teclado:
def __init__(self, master=None):

#data entry
    self.entry_var=StringVar()
    self.entry_text = Entry(self.frame_master, textvariable=self.entry_var, widt=10)
    self.entry_text.config(relief=RIDGE)
    self.entry_text.pack()

def act_acp(self):
    self.miCon = sqlite3.connect("base")
    self.miCur = self.miCon.cursor()
    while value(self.entry_var)!=9:
        self.entry_var= input("what up?")
        if (len(self.entry_var)!=9):
            print("tienes que introducir 9 caracteres")
        else:   
            self.miCur.execute("INSERT INTO REGISTRO2 VALUES(NULL,  '" + 
     self.entry_var.get()+"')")
    self.miCon.commit()
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error se debe a que para conocer el número de caracteres que contiene la `StringVar` debes obtener la cadena con el método `get` y pasarla a `len()`:

```
if len(self.entry_var.get()) != 9:
```

No obstante lo anterior no es tu problema real, ten mucho cuidado con los ciclos infinitos en una GUI, nunca jamás debes bloquear el mainloop o de lo contrario tu aplicación dejará de responder a eventos y se congelará. Ese ciclo `while value` es un ciclo mortal para el mainloop, queda bloqueado indefinidamente porque para salir del ciclo hace falta que se pueda modificar el `Entry` y esto no puede ocurrir si el mainloop está bloqueado, el resultado es una aplicación que deja de responder.

> Cualquier ciclo o llamada a función/método que tarde en terminar o retornar llamado en el hilo principal son potenciales bloqueadores del mainloop y causantes de que la interfaz deje de responder.

Voy a asumir que se lanza la consulta cuando se pulsa <kbd>Enter</kbd> en el `Entry`. Dado que, para ser válida la entrada, ésta tiene que tener nueve caracteres, ni más ni menos, yo personalmente dividiría la validación en dos partes:

- Usar `validate="key"` junto [`validatecommand`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/entry-validation.html) para ir validando dinámicamente el contenido a la vez que se modifica el `Entry`. Esto nos sirve para impedir que se escriban más de nueve caracteres y ,adicionalmente, podríamos validar el propio texto ingresado, por ejemplo habilitar solo el ingreso de dígitos.
- Crear un evento que se lance al pulsar `Enter` una vez ingresado el texto. Esto lanzaría la consulta a la base de datos. Si la entrada tiene nueve caracteres y no menos se lanza la consulta a la BD, si no, se puede mostrar un mensaje de alerta.

Un ejemplo reproducible:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox



class Teclado(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)
        self.entry_var = tk.StringVar()
        vcmd = (self.register(self.on_validate), '%P')
        self.entry_text = tk.Entry(self,
                                   validate="key",
                                   validatecommand=vcmd,
                                   textvariable=self.entry_var,
                                   widt=10
                                   )
        self.entry_text.bind('<Return>', self.on_enter)
        self.entry_text.config(relief=tk.RIDGE)
        self.entry_text.pack()

    def on_validate(self, P):
        if len(P) > 9:
            self.bell()
            return False
        return True

    def on_enter(self, event):
        text = self.entry_var.get()
        if len(text) < 9:
            self.bell()
            messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Debe ingresar nueve caracteres")
        else:   
            print(text)
            # self.miCur.execute("INSERT INTO REGISTRO2 VALUES(NULL,  %s)", text)
            # self.miCon.commit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Teclado(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.geometry("200x50+0+0")
    root.mainloop()
```

Dos apuntes:

- Usar *wildcard* para importar (`from tkinter import*`) es una mala práctica generalmente a no ser que esté justificado su uso. Es peligroso (propicia errores por solapamiento indeseado de espacios de nombres) y dificulta la legibilidad del código.
- No generes la query usando métodos de formateo de cadenas de Python, menos aún cuando se usan entradas de usuario crudas para ello. Esto pone muy fácil los ataques de inyección de código a tu base de datos. En su lugar parametriza, por ejemplo:

  ```
  self.miCur.execute("INSERT INTO REGISTRO2 VALUES(NULL,  %s)", (self.entry_var.get(), ))
  ```